# Error when trying to restore from .bak to 2 new databases, "Database in use"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a .bak file called PublishingEngine_03102019.bak. I would like to restore this back twice, once to a DB called `PublishingEngine` (the original name of the source database) and again to a DB called `PublishingEngine_Dev`.

I can do the original restore just fine. I now have a DB called `PublishingEngine`. Now I'm trying to do the second backup. But I get this error:

> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use

I've changed the name of the database in the Destination Database field. Do I need to change it anyplace else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Options page check "Close existing connections to destination database".

Comment: Ok, thanks! And just to be sure, this will leave alone the database called "PublishingEngine"?  Correct?  It's not going to impact that one at all?

Comment: As long as that is not your destination database, yes.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering.  See the updated pic in the OP. I'm worried that the name I circled in blue still says "PublishingEngine" even though I changed the name that is circled in red.

Comment: No, that's fine. SSMS just recognizes that you are using the latest backup of `PublishingEngine` as your source.

Answer (score 0):

In the option section in restoring wizard change the name of the ldf and mdf files or set other directory rather than the default ones..i guess it will solve the problem..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The ability to change the file names is in "Files" and not "Options". But even in "files" they are already changed to PublishingEngine_Original.mdf and PublishingEngine_Original_log.ldf

Answer (score 0):

I ended up renaming the existing database first, and then the second restore ran w/o a problem.